# How to set up Spark with a single-node MemSql cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, singlestore

I have a Single Node MemSql cluster:

- RAM: 16GM
- Core: 4
- Ubuntu 14.04

I have Spark deployed on this Memsql for ETL purpose.

I am unable to configure spark on Memsql.

1. How do I set rotation policy for Spark Work directory: `/var/lib/memsql-ops/data/spark/install/work/`
2. How can I change the path?
3. How large should `spark.executor.memory` be set to avoid OutOfMemoryExceptions?

How to set different configuration settings for Spark which has been deployed on Memsql cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully the following will fix your issue:

1. See `spark.worker.cleanup.enabled` and related configuration options: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/spark-standalone.html
2. The config can be changed in `/var/lib/memsql-ops/data/spark/install/conf/spark_{master,worker}.conf`. once the configuration is changed, you must restart the spark cluster with `memsql-ops spark-component-stop --all` and then `memsql-ops spark-component-start --all`

Comment: Setting these parameters didn't help, I have added more parameters spark.worker.cleanup.interval      1800
spark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl    14400 Will check if that Helps

Comment: Let me know if those additional configs help.  Did you try setting a larger executor memory value in the config files I mentioned?  That should solve your memory issues.